# How to reference a public field of java.awt.Dimension from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-java-interop

Is it possible in Kotlin to directly access a public backing-field declared in a Java class, if that class happens to have the corresponding getter for the field? For example, JDK's `java.awt.Dimension` has the fields `width` and `height`, which are `public`, but also there are `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods (although they return `double`s instead of `int`s, so they are not strictly 'corresponding' getters). Here is a sample code:

```
fun obtainWidth(): Int {
    val size = Dimension(1, 2)
    return size.width
}
```

The Java bytecode clearly shows the method `getWidth()` being called, followed by a `double`-to-`int` conversion:

```
  public final static obtainWidth()I
   L0
    NEW java/awt/Dimension
    DUP
    ICONST_1
    ICONST_2
    INVOKESPECIAL java/awt/Dimension.<init> (II)V
    ASTORE 0
   L1
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/awt/Dimension.getWidth ()D
    D2I
    IRETURN
```

Interestingly, if I replace `width` with `getWidth()`, then code does not compile, requiring explicit conversion.

I use Kotlin v1.3.61